# when i subscribeon an another schduler ,subscibe does not work any more

Tags: android, rx-java

***the following code does not print anything,puzzled me ***
when i remove subscribeon ,it works,print what i want

```
Observable observable = Observable.<String>create(subscriber -> {
                try {
                    subscriber.onNext("1");
                    System.out.println(" current thread is " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    subscriber.onNext("2");
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                    subscriber.onNext("3");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    subscriber.onNext("4");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    );

    observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).timeInterval().observeOn(Schedulers.immediate()).subscribe(n -> System.out.println(((TimeInterval) n).getIntervalInMilliseconds()
                    + "   value is  " + ((TimeInterval) n).getValue()),
            e -> System.out.println("onerror " + e),
            () -> System.out.println("oncomplete "));
```

Comment: akarnokd's is quite right,thank you very much.@akarnokd,I  want to ask an another question: what's the diffrence bettween Scheduler and thread

Answer (score 1):

Your main thread quits before the `subscribeOn` takes effect, try to sleep in the main thread as well or use `toBlocking().subscribe(...)`. Also note that `Schedulers.immediate()` executes tasks on the same thread that the value is received and **not** on the thread that assembled the sequence.

Comment: akarnokd's is quite right,thank you very much.@akarnokd,I want to ask an another question: what's the diffrence bettween Scheduler and thread

Comment: Scheduler is an abstraction that is often backed by a threadpool which runs on thread(s). You could also have a Scheduler backed by actors or fibers yet work with them the same way.